# How to add New Field in CC form?

Tags: magento2, database, payment-methods, forms, zipcode

I am using an extension for payment cc form,. I added zip code field in my cc form and I want to save `zipcode` from the `zipcode` field into my database. So, if user comes again there is no need to enter it again.

Where can I save `zipcode` in database in magento2.